# Android, looping through Parse data, assigning to ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am looping through data in Android, using Parse data.  I came up with this as a way to get user information; the larger goal is to create a model of data that I can use in an array adapter, so I can create a custom list view (as described [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)) In the example, the data are hard-coded, not pulled from a database.

```
public static ArrayList<Midwifefirm> getUsers() {

    //Parse data to get users
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

    query.orderByAscending(ParseConstants.KEY_PRACTICE_NAME);

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {

                final List<ParseUser> mMidwives;
                mMidwives = users;

                String usertype;

                String[] midwives = new String[mMidwives.size()];
                String[] yearsofexperience = new String[mMidwives.size()];
                String[] education = new String[mMidwives.size()];
                String[] philosophy = new String[mMidwives.size()];

                int i = 0;
                for (ParseUser user : mMidwives) {

                    usertype = user.getString("userType");

                    if (!Arrays.asList(midwives).contains(usertype) && usertype != "patient") {

                        midwives[i] = user.getString("practicename");
                        yearsofexperience[i] = user.getString("yearsofexperience");
                        education[i] = user.getString("education");
                        philosophy[i] = user.getString("practicephilosophy");

                        ArrayList<Midwifefirm> midwifefirm = new ArrayList<Midwifefirm>();
                        midwifefirm.add(new Midwifefirm(midwives[i], yearsofexperience[i], education[i], philosophy[i]));

                        return midwifefirm;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The intention is that for every user that does not have the type patient, collect this data about them, then store it in the arrayList.

On the return statement, though, there is an error: `cannot return a value from a method with a void return type.`

I may be over complicating this...read through various sources to get a model for this...in the end, I want to display a list of information about specific users, after the user makes a selection of a city...it would therefore display all the information about the medical practices in that city.

Thanks for your help

Michael

Comment: You are not closing your braces and you are returning twice. Is this a copy paste error or is it in the code?

Comment: Copy and paste error, I will update the code

Comment: why don't you declare arrays in class and then use setters and getters?

Comment: @shaz so: my mainActivity has: ArrayList<Midwifefirm> arrayOfUsers = Midwifefirm.getUsers(); call class where I am defining data, function getUsers: public static ArrayList<Midwifefirm> getUsers() {; within that function, I should declare ArrayList for each data point I want (education, experience, etc)?

Comment: yeah just declare the array in the class instead of in the method and keep everything same in the getUser function. also don't return anything from getUser method as array is in the class u can access from within the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code won't even compile in the form you sent it.

You make an asynchronous call when you use `findInBackground`. That means the code that calls it will just carry on after it calls it. It won't wait for it to finish, it doesn't care about it anymore.

The right way to deal with this type of code is by writing the logic you want and manipulating the results **in the callback**. So the first thing we change is the return type of `getUsers` to `void`.

Now `getUsers` merely says: "OK, please find this in background and from here I'll let you do your thing in `done()`".

```
public static void getUsers() {

    //Parse data to get users
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

    query.orderByAscending(ParseConstants.KEY_PRACTICE_NAME);

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {
                // here you manipulate your list. you set up your data structures 
                // or whatever and call other methods from your `Activity` or whatever, 
                // passing the data as parameter
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You will need to update the code that calls `getUsers` and needs the list of users, because, as you see, it can't get the results straight away. You may be able to move some of that code in `done`.

LE: You may also want to remove the `static` modifier from your method.

Comment: I realized I set this up wrong; I found this resource to help guide me http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-custom-listview-texts-tutorial/ which will help in addition to your answer